# After Migrating to AndroidX, My dataBinding includes android support libraries

Tags: android, binding, androidx

After migrating to AndroidX, generated data binding class includes android support libraries.

I have founded all question about `AndroidX DataBinding`.
But there are no answers that I want.
most of the answers were about

1.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true (already fixed)
```

2. Don't include android support code even if XML (I have no android support code everywhere)

3 .Update android studio version and Gradle version (My studio version is 3.4.2-latest and Gradle version is 4.10.1)

After enabling data binding at build.gradle like this.

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

and then when I build, generated files at GeneratedJava folder had android suuport.annotation always.

```
package com.******.******.******.******.databinding;
import com.******.******.******.******.R;
import com.******.******.******.******.BR;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.View;
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class NoticeListFragmentBinding extends 
android.databinding.ViewDataBinding  {
```

Also, at androidDependency, it has always

```
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.3@jar
```

If a added like this
    `all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'`

Generated NoticeListFragmentBinding class can't find annotation classes.

How to fix `Generated data binding class includes androids support library's classes`

Thanks